# custom built silicon carbide discs

Tags: toyota, brakes

My toyota corolla CE110 brake performance is not to the expectation, it takes an unusual amount of distance and requires comparatively hard braking to get it to stop. I had checked it by a mechanic and according to him it's all normal, but when I compare it with my friend's car it's not. So I was wondering if I fit high performance brake pads and discs will it fix the issue. I'm sure out of factory products are not available for this model (as it's too old now), so I might have to do a custom order for both brake discs and for pads. Before going and finding suppliers is there any other way to improve the braking performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Opinion

The cost of high performance pads and calipers seems like a very high cost for such an issue.  If you believe that the mechanic is correct and that there are no issues with the OEM products then perhaps looking for alternatives is sensible option.

Consider this.  When this Toyota rolled of the showroom floor and didn't stop well, is that the way that Toyota really designed this vehicle?  I think, probably not.

## Answer

1. Take the vehicle to another mechanic that shows humility and has the ability to say, "I'm not sure what's wrong" and get a brake job.
2. Do it yourself.

Doing it yourself would require a bit of research and some basic tools but you could pull it off for a very nominal cost.

- Get the discs turned or buy new ones.  Turning your discs is essentially getting a new surfaced machined to the discs.  Most issues with a disc regarding glazing or mild warping will be rectified and the disc can then be 'bedded in' to a new set of pads.
- Get new pads for your new disc surface.  Avoid high speed braking for a bit and allow them to mate together.  The surface of the pad and disc will become 'mated' over time and match.
- Buy a rebuilt master cylinder.  The master cylinder is the force behind the braking.  When you push the pedal it interacts with the master cylinder that performs the hydraulic work of displacing fluid in the system that pushing the caliper cylinder out, thus squeezing the disc with the brake pads.  If the master cylinder is going bad then your brakes will be miserable.  You can procure a refurbished one for a nominal cost.

Comment: I would add, check the rear brakes also. While the fronts do the majority of the stopping work misadjusted or non functional rears will increase stopping distance.